# Memoir: skip section numbers, make subsection numbers continuous within chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, memoir

Can the `memoir` class create a reference book whose table of contents would look like this:

```
Chapter 1. Animals

    Mammals
        Cows ................... 1.000
        Bulls .................. 1.001
        Calves ................. 1.002
    Amphibians
        Frogs .................. 1.003
        Turtles ................ 1.004
        Newts .................. 1.005

Chapter 2. Plants

    Trees
        Pines .................. 2.000
        Oaks ................... 2.001
        Maples ................. 2.002
    Shrubs
        Brambles ............... 2.003
        Brooms ................. 2.004
        Lilacs ................. 2.005
```

In particular I wish to:

1. Suppress `section` numbers both in the text and the table of contents.
2. Make `subsection` numbers continuous within a `chapter`.
3. Present the `subsection` numbers in the `X.YYY` format where `X` = chapter number.
4. Move the `subsection` numbers out to the margins. The idea is to use them instead of page numbers.

Comment: Not really no. The section number and title arrives at the toc as a single unit. It may be possible to separate them, but will be quite hard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic solution. You still have to modify the parameters for the table of contents for suppressing the chapter page number and the dots for the sections.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\counterwithout{subsection}{section} % subsection is not reset with section
\counterwithin{subsection}{chapter}  % subsection is reset with chapter

% subsection numbers are X.YYY
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thechapter.\threedigits{subsection}}
\newcommand{\threedigits}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{#1}<100 0\fi
  \ifnum\value{#1}<10 0\fi
  \arabic{#1}%
}

\setsecnumformat{\csname #1secnumformat\endcsname}
% no numbering shown for section titles
\newcommand\sectionsecnumformat{}
% numbering shown for subsection titles
\newcommand\subsectionsecnumformat{\thesubsection.\quad}

% modify the TOC macros not to use the section number
\makeatletter
\let\memoir@l@section\l@section
\def\l@section#1#2{%
  \mihai@gobble@number#1\@nil
}
\def\mihai@gobble@number\numberline#1#2\@nil{%
  \memoir@l@section{#2}{}%
}
% modify the TOC macros to use the subsection number as the page number
\let\memoir@l@subsection\l@subsection
\def\l@subsection#1#2{%
  \mihai@get@number#1\@nil
}
\def\mihai@get@number\numberline#1#2\@nil{%
  \memoir@l@section{#2}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\settocdepth{subsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\makeatletter\show\l@section
\tableofcontents*
\mainmatter
\chapter{Animals}
x
\section{Mammals}
x
\subsection{Cows}
x
\subsection{Bulls}
x
\subsection{Calves}
x

\section{Amphibians}
x
\subsection{Frogs}
x
\subsection{Turtles}
x
\subsection{Newts}
x

\chapter{Plants}
x
\section{Trees}
\subsection{Pines}
x
\subsection{Oaks}
x
\subsection{Maples}
x
\section{Shrubs}
x
\subsection{Brambles}
x
\subsection{Brooms}
x
\subsection{Lilacs}
x

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. That's quite a hack for a 'basic solution'! ;-) Many thanks, egreg. The compiler gives me an error in the part modifying the TOC macros, but at least thanks to you I have something to play with and learn along the way.